# Prevent Selecting Same value in multiple dropdown working fine but after click add / Delete button then prevent duplication function not working

Tags: javascript

I have six interface list in option menu , but in future it may be increases.I want when someone click on add button then it shows only rest interface list that are not selected before in option menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 3; //Input fields increment limitation
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
  var fieldHTML = '<div>' +
    '<select name="name[]" class="select">' +
    '<option value="">Select</option>' +
    ' <option value="eth0">eth0</option> ' +

    '<option value="eth1">eth1</option>' +

    '<option value="eth2">eth2</option>' +
    '<option value="eth3">eth3</option>' +
    '<option value="eth4">eth4</option>' +

    '<option value="eth5">eth5</option>' +
    '<option value="eth6">eth6</option>' +

    '</select>' +


    '<select name="name[]" class="select">' +
    '<option value="">Select</option>' +
    ' <option value="eth0">eth0</option> ' +

    '<option value="eth1">eth1</option>' +

    '<option value="eth2">eth2</option>' +
    '<option value="eth3">eth3</option>' +
    '<option value="eth4">eth4</option>' +

    '<option value="eth5">eth5</option>' +
    '<option value="eth6">eth6</option>' +

    '</select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">Delete</a></div>'; //New input field html 

  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(addButton).click(function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter
      $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
    }
  });

  //Once remove button is clicked
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
  });
});

$('select').change(function() {
  var myOpt = [];
  $("select").each(function() {
    myOpt.push($(this).val());
  });
  $("select").each(function() {
    $(this).find("option").prop('hidden', false);
    var sel = $(this);
    $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
      if ((value != "") && (value != sel.val())) {
        sel.find("option").filter('[value="' + value + '"]').prop('hidden', true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container" style="  padding:30px;">
  <form method="post" action="dashboard.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email"> Interface</label>
          <select name="name[]" class="select">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
            <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
            <option value="eth2">eth2</option>
            <option value="eth3">eth3</option>
            <option value="eth4">eth4</option>
            <option value="eth5">eth5</option>
            <option value="eth6">eth6</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="field_wrapper">
          <div>
            <select name="name[]" class="select">
              <option value="">Select Pair</option>
              <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
              <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
              <option value="eth2">eth2</option>
              <option value="eth3">eth3</option>
              <option value="eth4">eth4</option>
              <option value="eth5">eth5</option>
              <option value="eth6">eth6</option>
            </select>
            <select name="name[]" class="select">
              <option value="">Select Pair</option>
              <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
              <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
              <option value="eth2">eth2</option>
              <option value="eth3">eth3</option>
              <option value="eth4">eth4</option>
              <option value="eth5">eth5</option>
              <option value="eth6">eth6</option>
            </select><br>
            <select name="name[]" class="select">
              <option value="">Select Pair</option>
              <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
              <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
              <option value="eth2">eth2</option>
              <option value="eth3">eth3</option>
              <option value="eth4">eth4</option>
              <option value="eth5">eth5</option>
              <option value="eth6">eth6</option>
            </select>
            <select name="name[]" class="select">
              <option value="">Select Pair</option>
              <option value="eth0">eth0</option>
              <option value="eth1">eth1</option>
              <option value="eth2">eth2</option>
              <option value="eth3">eth3</option>
              <option value="eth4">eth4</option>
              <option value="eth5">eth5</option>
              <option value="eth6">eth6</option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried many things but didn't work. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: *I have tried many things but didn't work* **is not a helpful problem description**. Please narrow down your question by pointing out your best attempt and explain how it fails, and what you expect instead.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but consider using a `<button>` rather than an anchor with an `href="javascript:void(0);"`. Unless that anchor is supposed to take you to another page, it should be a button with `type="button"`.

Comment: Thank you I will change that but now I need prevent duplication functionality working after click on add link.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is your newly created `select` don't get assign change event.

Instead of

```
$('select').change(function() {
   ...
});
```

Try

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: I tried but still it's not working